Is `Restart-Computer -Force` equivalent to `shutdown /r /t 0`?
I'm trying to abstract some scripts so that they function on multiple OSes. I'd like to ensure that there's no change in functionality on Windows without introducing multiple code paths.
I ask because official documentation appears to demonstrate that -Force merely reduces the timeout to 0s, whereas https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19791#issue-1754765900 appears to demonstrate that -Force also does not cater for non-responsive processes.

@VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle, damnit, I meant to type Restart-Computer! Really sorry. I've fixed it. I proofread it a million times, and yet somehow didn't notice that I referenced the wrong bloody command.

Restart-Computer -Force does more than set the timer to zero (the linked issue is only for the macOS version of powershell). You can verify this by attempting to restart while a user is logged on for example
The commands are not quite the same. shutdown does have its own force /f parameter (equivalent to Restart-Computer -Force). Your command sets /t 0, so the reboot is not forced - the documentation mentions:

/t <xxx> If the timeout period is greater than 0, the /f parameter is implied.

